# Exchanged Foreign Key on Entity Framework Code First From data base

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm making a Windows Service using Code First From Database, but my code is throwing the following exception. Where can I change Foreign Key configuration of this class, because it looks like that the columns are cross-referenced, the column `usu_grpcom` must refer `codagp` and `usu_codemp` must refer `codemp`.

> e013agp_usu_titefol_Source_e013agp_usu_titefol_Target: :  The types of
>   all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential  constraint must
>   be the same as the corresponding property types in the  Principal
>   Role.  The type of property 'usu_grpcom' on entity 'usu_titefol' does
>   not match the  type of property 'codemp' on entity 'e013agp' in the
>   referential constraint  'e013agp_usu_titefol'.
>
> e013agp_usu_titefol_Source_e013agp_usu_titefol_Target: :  The types of
>   all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential  constraint must
>   be the same as the corresponding property types in the  Principal
>   Role.  The type of property 'usu_codemp' on entity 'usu_titefol' does
>   not match the  type of property 'codagp' on entity 'e013agp' in the
>   referential constraint  'e013agp_usu_titefol'.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you should share the classes implementation for better understanding. I'm providing you code according to my understanding. You can use the similar code to solve your problem.

```
public class usu_titefol
{
    public e013agp e013agp { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("codemp")]
    [Required]
    public int usu_grpcom { get; set; }
}
```